# how to increment value by +1 by clicking button in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

am stuck with a problem when I click on like button I want it increment by +1, can anyone tell me how can I do it, I try it but I can't solve it.
below I share my all code that I used to make my small application. if you have question free feel to ask me.

> Music.js

This is my music form where I wrote my whole code.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ExitToAppIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExitToApp';
import RadioIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Radio';
import firebase from '../Firebase';
import SearchBar from "material-ui-search-bar";
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container, Input, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import './Music.css';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import ThumbUpAltIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUpAlt';
// import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';




const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    title: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    search: {
        marginTop: 30,
    },
    table: {
        minWidth: 650,
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    cells: {
        marginTop: 50,
    },
    thumb: {
        color: '#e75480',
    },
    name: {
        color: 'blue',
        padding: 10,
        fontSize: 20,
    },
    audios: {
        display: 'flex',
        margin: 'auto',
        height: 50,
        width: 500,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    icon: {
        fontSize: 40,
        color: '#e75480',
        cursor:'pointer'
    }
}));

const Music = () => {

    const history = useHistory();
    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    const [like, setLike] = useState(false);

    const [music,setMusics] = useState([
        {
            id:"1",
            name:"Arijit singh",
            audiosrc:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Bicycle-bell.wav",
        },
        {
            id:"2",
            name:"Atif Aslam",
            audiosrc:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Bicycle-bell.wav",
        },
        {
            id:"3",
            name:"Sonu Nigam",
            audiosrc:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Bicycle-bell.wav",
        },
        {
            id:"4",
            name:"Neha kakkar",
            audiosrc:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Bicycle-bell.wav",
        },
    ])


     const likeButton = (id)=>{
         const likebuttons = music.find((curElem)=>{
            return curElem.id == id
         })
         setLike({likebuttons:like+1})
         console.log(likebuttons);
     }
    console.log(search);


    // Logout Functionality
    const Logout = () => {
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
            alert("Logout Successfull...");
            history.push('/');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static" style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="menu">
                        <RadioIcon style={{ fontSize: "30px" }} />&nbsp; React Music
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                    </Typography>
                    <Button color="inherit" onClick={Logout}> <ExitToAppIcon /> Logout </Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <Container>
                <SearchBar className={classes.search}
                    value={search}
                    onChange={(newValue) => setSearch(newValue)}
                />
                <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
                    <TableBody>
                        {music && music.map(mus=>{
                            return(
                                <TableRow>
                                <TableCell style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
                                    <div>
                                        <h3>{like} <ThumbUpAltIcon className={classes.icon} onClick={()=>likeButton(music.id)} /> {mus.name}</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <audio ref={inputRef} src={mus.audiosrc} className={classes.audios} controls />
                                    </div>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                            )
                        })}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </Container>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Music;
```

Comment: Your like type is a boolean try to pass a number in the uses rate instead of false

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your code:

```
const [like, setLike] = useState(false);
```

to

```
const [like, setLike] = useState(0);
```

and

```
setLike({likebuttons:like+1})
```

to

```
setLike(like+1);
```

and try again.

Comment: I did it but its not working, thanks for giving your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make type as number instead of boolean

```
const [like, setLike] = useState(0);
```

and then

```
const likeButton = (id)=>{
         const likebuttons = music.find((curElem)=>{
            return curElem.id == id
         })
         setLike(likebuttons+1);
         console.log(likebuttons);
     }
```

Or

> you can add no. of likes in same array object and just update that like field

You can check below example created for you. I hope it will help you.

**It's having only like functionality**

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [likedSong, setLikedSong] = useState({
    likes: 0,
    id: 0
  });
  const [music, setMusics] = useState([
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Arijit singh",
      audiosrc:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Bicycle-bell.wav",
      likes: 0
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Atif Aslam",
      audiosrc:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Bicycle-bell.wav",
      likes: 0
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Sonu Nigam",
      audiosrc:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Bicycle-bell.wav",
      likes: 0
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      name: "Neha kakkar",
      audiosrc:
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Bicycle-bell.wav",
      likes: 0
    }
  ]);
  const handleLike = (list) => {
    if (likedSong.id === list.id) {
      setLikedSong({ ...likedSong, id: list.id, likes: ++likedSong.likes });
    } else {
      setLikedSong({ ...likedSong, id: list.id, likes: 0 });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {music.map((mus) => (
        <div key={mus.id} className="music-list">
          <div>
            {mus.id === likedSong.id && (
              <span className="no-likes">{likedSong.likes}</span>
            )}
            <span className="btn-like" onClick={() => handleLike(mus)}>
              Like
            </span>
            {mus.name}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Live working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/likes-onmh9)

Comment: I did it but its not working, thanks for giving your valuable time

Comment: @MonuPatil can you check example provided...i hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have like count for all music data,

First you should change like state to store object

```
const [like, setLike] = useState({});
```

Change your like button function to store data in object

```
const likeButton = (musicId)=>{
  setLike({...like, like[musicId]: like[musicId] + 1 || 1 })
}
```

Now change how you are showing like count as  below:

```
<div>
  <h3>{like[music.id]} <ThumbUpAltIcon className={classes.icon} onClick={()=>likeButton(music.id)} /> {mus.name}</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you should change your states.
each music has it's own like number, so you can't use 1 like state for all.
each item in your music array should have a value to store it's own like
numbers.
something like :

```
const [music,setMusics] = useState([
      {
         id:"1",
         name:"Arijit singh",
         audiosrc:"https://uploa...",
         likeNumbers:0,
       },
    ...
    ]
```

then your onClick should iterate the music array, find the clicked item and change it's likeNumbers value.
something like this:

```
cosnt handleClick = (id) => {
    setMusic((prevState) => prevState.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === id ) {
            return {...item, likeNumbers:likeNumbers + 1 }       
        } else {
            return item
        }
    })
}
```

to be clear:
first you should take the last version of your state, then in the process of iterating, find the clicked item and update it. to avoid mutate your state ( because items are objects ), you should make a copy first, then changed it. I mean here:

```
return {...item, likeNumbers:likeNumbers + 1 }
```

after all a part of your jsx code should be changed to :

```
<h3>{mus.likeNumber} <ThumbUpAltIcon className={classes.icon} onClick={()=>likeButton(music.id)} /> {mus.name}</h3>
```